# C#. Почему не отправляется(или не приходят) email сообщения?

Tags: c#

```
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("мояпочта@yandex.ru", "Tom");
MailAddress to = new MailAddress("тожемоянодругая@gmail.com");
MailMessage m = new MailMessage(from, to);
m.Subject = "Тест";
m.Body = "Письмо-тест 2 работы smtp-клиента";
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.yandex.com", 25);
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("мояпочта@yandex.ru", "мойпароль");
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Send(m);
```

Не знаю в чем может быть проблема. В верности почт и пароля я уверен.

Я так понял что `to` и `networkCredentials` это по факту она и та же почта, только с паролем.
Тестил порты `25, 465, 587` - без разницы.

Что можно еще попробовать?

P.S> Немного прогресса. Стала дропаться ошибка `{"Неправильная последовательность команд. Отклик сервера: 5.5.4 Error: send AUTH command first."}`. Раньше не дропалось ничего)

Comment: вы в 6 строчке указали yandex.com, попробуйте поменять домен на .ru.

Comment: 25 порт скорее всего заблокирован вашим провайдером (и это нормально). Но `SmtpClient` не поддерживает явный SSL, поэтому ему нужен 25 порт. Объехать проблему можно [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29551513/12888024).

Comment: @vanyavanya не помогло(

Comment: @AskAlexandria, у вас порт заблокирован. Выше уже кинули решение.

Comment: @aepot я думаю что не блокирует. Самый первый раз когда запускал отправку - она сработала, а потом какие бы данные не вбивал - просто перестала. Даже если ввести те же самые.

Comment: @vanyavanya даже выкладывал код на купленный сервер с разблоченным 25 - тоже ноль результата

Comment: @AskAlexandria, проблема может быть и на стороне Яндекса. Попробуйте использовать обычный Mail.ru.

Comment: Почитайте ответы по ссылке.